# Ошибка после переключения между вкладками Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

После переключения на вторую вкладку во время теста происходит ввод логина и пароля и после чего, происходит переход на следующую страницу и тест падает. Но ни какой ошибки не отображается, либо отображается старая ошибка (которая была еще на предыдущей страницу), что это может быть?

Вот часть кода теста:

```
 WebActions.Navigation.NavigateToUrl(Constants.BASE_URL);
        WebActions.Login.InputCredentials(Constants.USER_NAME, Constants.PASSWORD);

        Assert.AreEqual(Constants.USER_NAME, Pages.TopBar.GetProfileName());

        WebActions.SideBarActions.GoToSecondTab();

        bool check = true;
        while (check)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < BaseTest.driver.WindowHandles.Count; i++)
            {
                if (BaseTest.driver.SwitchTo().Window(BaseTest.driver.WindowHandles[i]).Title.Equals(title))
                {
                    BaseTest.driver.SwitchTo().Window(BaseTest.driver.WindowHandles[i]);
                    check = false;
                }
            }
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Title: " + BaseTest.driver.Title);

        Pages.HangfireControlLoginPage.ClickToFirstLoginButton();
        WebActions.HangfireControlPanelLoginActions.DoLogin(Constants.USER_NAME, Constants.PASSWORD);
Pages.HangfireControlPanelDashboardPage.WaitForPageToLoad();
        Assert.IsTrue(Pages.HangfireControlPanelDashboardPage.IsPageHeaderVisible());
```

На строке

```
WebActions.HangfireControlPanelLoginActions.DoLogin(Constants.USER_NAME, Constants.PASSWORD);
```

происходит вход на сайт, логинится успешно, и падает сразу после перехода на следующую страницу. После чего тест останавливается, но браузер не закрывается. Лога в IDE (успешен тест, или упавший) - нет (тест как будто не запускался).

Вот код для Dologin():

```
public void DoLogin(string userName, string password)
    {
        Pages.HangfireControlLoginPage.ClickToUserNameField();
        Pages.HangfireControlLoginPage.TypeToUserNameField(userName);
        Pages.HangfireControlLoginPage.ClickToPasswordField();
        Pages.HangfireControlLoginPage.TypeToPasswordField(password);
        Pages.HangfireControlLoginPage.ClickToLoginButton();
    }
```

Comment: Какой браузер, что за ошибки? Где логи селениума? Где хоть какая-то конкретика?

Comment: @Andrew Вот и я о том же, логов нет, потому что после переключения на вторую вкладку, происходит логирование на сайте, и селениум перестает отвечать, перестает искать локаторы, и просто тест останавливается как буд-то и не был запущен и сам Хром не закрываетсяю. В случае если есть какае то ошибка в первой вкладке (перед переключением на вторую), то тест падает и с логом, что упал в такой то строке, и по такой то причине.

Comment: Тогда где хотя бы код теста? Или будем ждать, пока в вопрос заглянут телепаты?

Comment: Скиньте в чем заключается тест, наверняка у вас не находится какой-то элемент, который жестко забит в коде и из за этого падает.

Comment: @MainStar при чем здесь логи сайта? Каждое создание инстанса селениума создает логи во временных файлах, про которые, ты, судя по всему, не знаешь. Их нужно время от времени чистить ибо они неплохо так занимают места. По-хоршему твои тесты так же должны создавать свои отдельные логи от тех, которые создает селениум. В вопросе нету ни малейшего намека на информацию, которую можно использовать в помощь.

Comment: @Andrew по поводу логов сайта речь и не шла. Я добавил в описание проблемы часть кода теста и с описанием в каих строках он падает.

Comment: значит кинь код еще для `WebActions.HangfireControlPanelLoginActions.DoLogin`

Comment: @Andrew я добавил код метода WebActions.HangfireControlPanelLoginActions.DoLogin

Comment: перепроверь правильность занесенных локаторов логин и пасворд полей внутри Pages.HangfireControlLoginPage. А так же попробуй отдебажить этот метод.

Comment: Этот метод работает коректно, тест падает после него, когда переходит на следующую страницу. Вернее когда перешел, дождался отображения шапки сайта, и после этого упал. Я сейчас еще добавлю лог который получаю, потому что у меня каким то образом получается ошибка StackOverFlow.

Comment: Вот ссылка на скрин с логом. http://prntscr.com/m04j6q

Comment: 1. Что за жесть с Thread.Sleep на 10 секунд?... 2. При чем здесь то, что хеадер визибл относительно правильности локаторов полей логина и пароля?

Comment: 3. При чем заметь, у тебя буквально перед этим вызовом `WebDriverTimeOutException` что тебе буквально намекает на то, что селениум пытался что-то найти и не нашел и файлонулся по таймауту. То есть... У тебя неправильный локатор записан с вероятностью в 99.99%

Comment: @Andrew 1. предпологалось, что может быть не хватает времени для ожидания, по этому тот слип  2. В том, что этот хедер находится после полей логина и пароля, если быть более точным, то тот проверяеиый хедер появляется на следующей странице после авторизации.

Comment: 1. слипы в тестах использовать это **ОЧЕНЬ** плохой тон. Все должно регулироватся через таймауты, а так же Implicit, Explicit, Fluent Wait. Это убыстряет прохождение тестов В ДЕСЯТКИ, а иногда и СОТНИ раз. Это что бы ты понимал всю масштабность костыля.. 2.да не важно. Проверь правильность локаторов полей. Хеадер визибилити к правильности локаторов полей отношения не имеет ни малейшего.

Comment: @Andrew да, не имеет, но я пологаю, что локаторы все таки верны если во время тесты в них тапается и логин и пароль?

Comment: не факт) Нужно проверять в дебаге. Возможно именно в тот момент или именно на том адресе эти локаторы уже не верны. Не просто же так валится по таймауту